# Terraform provider Azure - is there a way to add customer_managed_key to SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, terraform-provider-azure

is there a way to add customer_managed_key to the SQL server as there is to storage account?

Comment: Do you mean you want to using the customer_managed_key connect to the Storage account?

Comment: 1. Click On `Transparent data encryption`
2. Set `Use your own key` to `YES`
3. Browse through your `key vaults` to Select an existing key or create a new key in Key Vault.
4. Check `Make selected key the default TDE protector`

using Terraform

Comment: I do have the same problem..any solution ? [An old ticket](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/87) but can't find the block

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add `customer_managed_key` to the SQL server but it's not because of the storage account which is mainly used for backup/restore process and retain logs.

From the document---[Azure SQL Transparent Data Encryption with customer-managed key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/transparent-data-encryption-byok-overview), we could know that the key used for encryption of the Database Encryption Key (DEK), called TDE protector, is a customer-managed asymmetric key stored in a customer-owned and customer-managed Azure Key Vault (AKV), a cloud-based external key management system.

You can use a key stored in your Azure Key Vault to encrypt the TDE for your SQL server. However, there are no built-in blocks of support in terraform resource [azurerm_sql_server](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/sql_server.html) or I can not find it yet. You could use Azure CLI to implement it and invoke a local executable via [local-exec Provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html).

You may use the following.

Add the Key vault key to the server and set the TDE protector

```
az sql server key create --server <servername> --resource-group <rgname> --kid <keyID>

az sql server tde-key set --server <servername> --server-key-type AzureKeyVault -- resource-group <rgname> --kid <keyID>
```

Enable TDE at the database level. Note that the encryption could take a while depending on the database size and the tier.

```
az sql db tde set --database <dbname> --server <servername> --resource-group <rgname> --status Enabled
```

Check Encryption state and activity using CLI or Powershell or TSQL CLI.

```
az sql db tde list-activity --database <dbname> --server <servername> --resource-group <rgname> # get whether encryption is on or off az sql db tde show --database <dbname> --server <servername> --resource-group <rgname>
```

Here are two detailed blogs for your references:

- http://thewindowsupdate.com/2020/05/29/public-preview-tde-with-customer-managed-keys-on-azure-sql-hyperscale/
- http://www.bradleyschacht.com/bring-your-own-key-to-azure-sql-database-managed-instance-tde/

Comment: Hi, I'm talking about doing it using Terraform, not CLI.

Comment: Terraform might also do it with the local-exec Provisioner.

Comment: I don't see how TF is supporting this.

Comment: Yes, terraform has no built-in block support, I mean you can use local-exec to invoke the CLI scripts to do it with terraform. local-exec provisioner helps run a script on the instance where we are running our terraform code, not on the resource we are creating. See more [samples](https://blog.logrocket.com/dirty-terraform-hacks/).